# Having issues when attempting to load images into a bitmap/Picture Box Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am attempting to load images into an Picture Box using the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Clear the Image Area
    if (templateArea.Image != null)
    { templateArea.Image = null; }

    //Set Base Variables
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Resources.BlankBackground);
    Graphics gpx = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;
    string bitmapToLoad;
    ResourceManager rm;

    //Loop Lists
    for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count; i++)
    {
        bitmapToLoad = Convert.ToString(comps[i][3]);
        rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
        newBitmap = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(bitmapToLoad);
        gpx.DrawImage(newBitmap,
            Convert.ToInt32(comps[i][4]),
            Convert.ToInt32(comps[i][5]),
            newBitmap.Width,
            newBitmap.Height);
        gpx.Dispose();
        }

        //Set Image Area to newBitmap
        templateArea.Image = newBitmap;
}
```

when trying to run the code I get errors on the second loop where i = 1 in this portion:

```
        gpx.DrawImage(newBitmap,
            Convert.ToInt32(comps[i][4]),
            Convert.ToInt32(comps[i][5]),
            newBitmap.Width,
            newBitmap.Height);

//given error: System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.' //Does not point to anything specific.
```

the comps list contains lists formatted as such:

```
//These listed items are defaulted at program start but more are added while running
//                           p elementName  type     sub type          x y sX  sY  R  G  B  O i
eleComps = new List<Object> {0,"Background","Static","BlankBackground",0,0,100,100,50,50,50,0,0};
comps.Add(eleComps);
eleComps = new List<Object> {0,"Border",    "Static","CardBorder_02",  0,0,100,100,50,50,50,0,0};
comps.Add(eleComps);
eleComps = new List<Object> {0,"Cut Line",  "Static","00_Card_CutLine",0,0,100,100,50,50,50,0,0};
comps.Add(eleComps);
```

Each possible "sub type" is a bitmap file in resources, and there are more than just those listed above.

What I have tried:
I have consulted the miracle that is Google and YouTube and haven't been able to solve this one. Although I feel like I'm missing something basic I have been looking at it all day and may need some fresh eyes on it to correct something that may be obvious but for some reason I seem to be missing.

What I am looking for:
I am trying to create an image viewer that will overlap images or parts of images (.png) at specific coordinates in an Picture Box. The comps list will be added to and removed from actively during application use and as such using a variable to reference the Resources is necessary and that portion of the code has given me the most difficult time out of the supplied code samples.

UPDATE 1: changed image box to picture box to reduce confusion.

UPDATE 2: NOTE: This sample achieves the desired end result, but does not allow me to use the variables as needed to change positions, scale, color, and opacity.

```
        //Clear Img Area
        templateArea.InitialImage = null;

        //Find Bitmap(s)
        string p = @"C:\Users\david\Desktop\Test Fields\Default\";
        Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(p + "00_Empty.png", true);
        Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(p + "CardBorder_02.png", true);
        Bitmap img3 = new Bitmap(p + "00_Card_CutLine.png", true);

        //Set initial image for image area
        Graphics gpx = Graphics.FromImage(img1);

        //place an image at x, y, Width,      Height
        gpx.DrawImage(img2, 0, 0, img2.Width, img2.Height);
        gpx.DrawImage(img3, 0, 0, img3.Width, img3.Height);

        //clear gpx cache
        gpx.Dispose();

        //set image area to modified img1
        templateArea.Image = img1;
```

Also please let me know if I'm just plain going about this in the wrong way, and what I need to do to get it right.

UPDATE 3: I seem to have gotten it to work properly with this variation, using the originally supplied list of listed parameters. Thanks to Idle_Mind's pointers I was able to figure it out.

```
    Bitmap newBitmap_01 = new Bitmap(templateArea.Width, templateArea.Height);
        Graphics gpx = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap_01);
        string bitmapToLoad;
        ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;
        Bitmap newBitmap_02;
        for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count; i++) 
        {
            bitmapToLoad = Convert.ToString(comps[i][3]);
            newBitmap_02 = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(bitmapToLoad);
            gpx.DrawImage(newBitmap_02,
                Convert.ToInt32(comps[i][4]),
                Convert.ToInt32(comps[i][5]),
                newBitmap_02.Width,
                newBitmap_02.Height);
        }
        gpx.Dispose();
        templateArea.Image = newBitmap_01;
```

Comment: There is no such things as an `ImageBox` also visual studio has nothing to do with this

Comment: You will either have to e.Graphics.DrawImage them onto the PictureBox __in its Paint event__ or combine them into a new Bitmap each time something changes. Then re-assign the new bitmap to pBox.Image. - If your issue is with the error your quote: What is `comps` and what are the values you need to convert (again and again?)??

Comment: comps is a list of lists, each list in comps contains the data for a specific element of the picture box. a sample would look like the 3rd code sample supplied. Also, I have corrected image box to picture box in my request for assistance.

Comment: the parts of a comps item that are set to change semi-regularly are x, y, sX, sY, r, g, b, o. representing position x, position y, scale x, scale y, red, green, blue, and opacity.

Comment: I'd definitely use the `e.Graphics` from the `Paint()` event if things are changing quite frequently.  Additionally, if `img1`, `img2` and `img3` don't change, then load them ONCE and store them at class level so you aren't reloading them each time you need to update your composite image.

Comment: The sample with img1, img2, and img3 are from the only variation of the sample that I could get to work so far, it is a testing variant in a sense. The plan is to replace those with a variable. So I can loop through a list of bitmaps. on that note i can try the e.Graphics and Paint() to see what results I get.